# SQL COMMAND returning empty result set for address

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to retrieve all employees whose address is in Houston,Texas from the a table called employee using the following command but i am getting an empty result. The tables have all the information in them with the correct employee address.

```
 select fname,lname 
 from   employee 
 where  address like '%Houston, TX%'
```

I have the Address as a VARCHAR I am not sure if that might be it. Thanks

This is the employee table used
[image]

Comment: Just a small point- use backticks ( ` ) around all fields. `select \`fname\`,\`lname\` 
 from   \`employee\` 
 where  \`address\` like '%Houston, TX%'`

Comment: can you try with  `where  address like '%Houston%'` or just `where  address like '%TX%'` ?

Comment: @ThomasLandauer Sure

Comment: Solved the issue apparently spacing matters(i did not know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to get rid of the wildcard at the end of the string, but that's not the reason this is happening. Perhaps there is a tab character, or more than one space?

```
 select fname,lname 
 from   employee 
 where  address like '%Houston, TX'
```

Comment: Solved the issue apparently spacing matters(i did not know)

Comment: @NBera great, what was the issue with the spacing?

Comment: i had Houston,TX when is was supposed to be Houston, TX

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL looks OK to me; VARCHAR is OK too. Maybe a minor typo somewhere (e.g. two spaces)? Or another whitespace character (e.g. tab)?

Try: `LIKE '%Houston%'` and see what happens.

Comment: Solved the issue apparently spacing matters(i did not know)